# QField Sync original project path missing

Tags: qgis, qfield, qfieldsync

I have a project in QGis, configured for QField. I moved that original project and all the files to a different folder. Now when i want to sync data back from my tablet using the QField-sync plugin, it says the Original path was not found - which is true, the path does not exist anymore. I do not understand why it matters though, i have set the project to relative paths so the data on the tablet should be synced to the new project folder without problems! How can i change the "original path" within Qfield, QGis, QField Sync etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thing is, the imported data does get written to the correct gpkg file. When running 'synchronize from qfield' I get the following message:

> QFieldSync : The data has been synchronized successfully but the original project (//original project location) could not be opened.

When you close the project after syncing and re-open the project, it will read the data from the modified gpkg and the newly added data should be there.

Saving the project in qgis and rerun 'Package for qfield' and using the new package should help, untill you relocate the project again.

Answer (score 0):

In our case, our server name changes on the top level every now and then (xxx-1 to xxx-2).

I realized that I need to export the qfield-project from the tablet and save it in some location. There, I open the "..._qfield.qgs"-file with a text editor and replace all file path with the correct one. Only replacing the project path is not sufficient (but helps to remove the error message about the lacking project file).
**I need to correct all path to sync the data and the project.**

I don't think this is well solved.